# Angular 2 RC6 Forms control validation message

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm" (submit)="onSubmit()">
    <label>Firstname:</label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="firstname">
    <p *ngIf="registerForm.controls.firstname.errors">This field is required!</p>
...
```

Is there any way to make `registerForm.controls.firstname.errors` little bit shorter?

Comment: RC2 example : <input #firstname=“ngForm” />
<p *ngIf=“firstname.errors”>…</p>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to define the shorter names as AbstractControl properties in your Form Component. In the respective Component Class, add:

```
firstname: AbstractControl;
```

And in the constructor:

```
this.firstname = this.registerForm.controls['firstname'];
```

Now, you can access the field properties like this:

```
<p *ngIf="firstname.errors">This field is required!</p>
```

[Source](http://blog.ng-book.com/the-ultimate-guide-to-forms-in-angular-2/)